# More pythonic way to handle this logic structure

Tags: python, loops, refactoring

I need to break up a length of numbers into chunks of 100 and what ever is left over and then add them to a final dictionary at the end.

I am able to do it with loops but I feel I might be missing something that would make this a much cleaner and efficient operation.

```
l = 238 # length of list to process
i = 0 #setting up count for while loop 
screenNames = {}#output dictionary
count = 0 #count of total numbers processed

while i < l:
    toGet = {}
    if l - count > 100:#blocks off in chunks of 100
        for m in range (0,100):
            toGet[count] = m
            count = count + 1
    else:
        k = count
        for k in range (0,(l - count)):#takes the remainder of the numbers 
            toGet[count] = k
            count = count + 1
        i = l   # kills loop  
    screenNames.update(toGet)
#This logic structure breaks up the list of numbers in chunks of 100 or their
#Remainder and addes them into a dictionary with their count number as the 
#index value

print 'returning:'
print screenNames
```

The above code works but it feels clunky does anyone have any better ways of handling this?

Comment: better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I didn't know we had that, I will use that from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I can see, you map a key `n` to the value `n % 100`, so this might be as well written as

```
screenNames = dict((i, i%100) for i in range(238))
print screenNames
```

Answer (score 1):

Running your code, it looks like you're just doing modular arithmetic:

```
l = 238 
sn = {}
for i in xrange(l):
    sn[i] = i % 100
print sn
```

Or more succinctly:

```
l = 238 
print dict((i, i % 100) for i in xrange(l))
```

That works by constructing a dictionary based on key-pair tuples.